# Every time I click a mouse, new browser window pops up on Lubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, mouse, lubuntu, bug

I just installed latest Lubuntu 32bit on my old laptop.

It isn't laggy but every time I left click a mouse (doesn't matter where), a new Firefox browser window starts. This is a clean install.
What could be a problem and fix to it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe run `xed` to see if anything else is being interpreted. I know some keyboards have a Browser key which sends a HID event to open a browser (which is interpreted by the OS) so maybe Lubuntu is somehow interpreting something wrong. Does it occur with any other mouse?

Also, which might seem obvious, but have you checked to see if there are any shortcuts set up to open Firefox with a mouse click? Does this occur on the Lubuntu Live USB?